# Import FTP project into Aptana

Tags: aptana-studio

I'm trying to get a regular PHP project on my FTP server into Aptana, but I can't seem to get it to work. When I look for help on their website it tells me to 'open the File View', but no matter how hard I look, I just don't have this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so apparently the solution was to click on Window -> Show View -> Remote, and then add a new ftp server from there.